# convert a string length to a hex value to add to List<byte>

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List that I'm adding 3 bytes to one of which is the length of a string that I'm dynamically passing to my method.  How can I determine the length of that string and convert the int into a value that would be accepted in my list.add() method.

Code below:

```
string myString = "This is a sample string...I need its length";
int theLength = myString.Length;
List<byte> lb = new List<byte>();
lb.Add(0x81);
lb.Add(theLength); // this doesn't work
lb.Add(0x04);
```

TIA

Comment: Does the string length need to be stored in 1 single byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the string's length is within the byte range:

```
lb.Add((byte)theLength);
```

Comment: doh!  not sure why I didn't think of trying this.  Thanks.  What would be maximum length of the string to fall in the byte range? <-- newb with bit/byte stuff sorry.

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson 255 characters at max but if you don't want to get into trouble, you should implement redneckjedi's suggestion which will work regardless of the size of the string. Be aware though that in this case the string's length will span multiple bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
lb.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(theLength))
```

Of course, you may decide you only need the least significant bit, in which case you could do a simple cast, or index into the result of GetBytes(), which will be 4 bytes long in this case.

More on BitConverter:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast your length into a `byte`:

```
lb.Add((byte)theLength);
```

But as you might guess, your length won't always fit into a single byte. Be more specific about what you expect to do with your list of bytes, we might could provide a better answer (such as using [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx)/[`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) instead of a list of bytes).